How is power supplied to relight a Raptor engine?
Estimates of the power consumed by Raptor turbopumps vary, but most are in the region of 100,000hp.
To restart a Raptor engine, presumably the turbines must be spun up to some sizable fraction of operating speed with either compressed gas or combustion of propellant. If propellant is used, it most be pumped into the preburner. Either way, significant energy is required.
If compressed gas is used, presumably it is in limited supply and the number of re-starts is limited.
How is this accomplished for re-start?

Close to the unanswered https://space.stackexchange.com/q/60354/6944

Isn't there a pre-burner where a small amount of propellant is combusted to drive the pumps? Or am I thinking of a different engine?

I answered the above "unanswered" question.

@Cadence I think that usually the turbopump is needed to pump that propellant into the preburner. So there is still an issue of starting it.

Both propellant tanks are pressurized to around 6 bar and that should be more than enough to initially push both propellants through the turbo pumps at whatever rate is required to prime and start them. Once propellants start burning in the preburners the turbopumps, a strong positive feedback will very rapidly boost the flow rate and power available to maximum. The turbines may also be prespun by compressed gas as part of the startup process. The start up process is reportedly very rapid and complex in terms of managing the exact flow rates, pressures and actions.

@Slarty that's similar to how the SSME started, using head pressure from the propellant tanks.

@Slarty ... is the compressed gas necessary to spin up the turbines? I ask because it is an inflight consumable and will determine the number of restarts. The 6 bar ullage pressure is unlimited as long as there is cryogenic propellant available to boil off.

@Woody I am not sure on that, but I think so. The 6 bar ullage pressure is unlimited under equilibrium conditions, but suddenly creating a lot of extra head space will leave it  far from equilibrium. I also suspect that they will rethink the helium later when they have the ship flying. Ideally they would use COPV methane and oxygen that could be replenished in flight via the autogenous pressurization, but there are some issues that need to be resolved first like ice in the oxygen tank.
